# In kendoUI how do you modify the event.response and event.type of requestEnd?

Tags: jquery, .net, model-view-controller, kendo-ui

**I managed to change the endpoint of kendoGrid.dataSource.transport.options.create.url and redirect it into a different endpoint**

is there a way to change the e.response and e.type in this code? code bellow. **I was talking about the parameter of the callback of requestEnd**

```
 requestEnd: function (e) {
            var response = e.response;
            var type = e.type;
            console.log(e, 'I am event');
            console.log("i triggered again and i am response", response);
            console.log("i am type", type);
            return 0;
            if (type !== "read") {
                toastr.options = {
                    positionClass: "toast-top-right"
                };
                if (type === 'update') {
                    if (!response.success) {
                        toastr.error(response.errorMessage, 'Account Update');
                    } else {
                        toastr.info('Acount detail successfully updated', 'Account Update');
                    }
                } else if (type === 'create') {
                    if (!response.success) {
                        toastr.error(response.errorMessage, 'Message');
                    } else {
                        toastr.info('New Account successfully added', 'Message');
                    }
                }

                $('#grid').data('kendoGrid').dataSource.read();
                $('#grid').data('kendoGrid').refresh();
            }
        },
```

**I really appreciate your help! anyone that could help me should deserve a raise :)**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would change approach to this problem. You can capture responses for each request based on type in `complete` section. Console log `response` and `errorThrown` to see what do you get from server

```
   transport: {
        read: {
            url: '',
            type: 'GET',,
            contentType: 'application/json',
            complete: function(response, errorThrown) {
                if (errorThrown === 'error') {
                     toastr.error(response.errorMessage, 'Account Read')
                } else {
                     var responseData = response.responseJSON.accounts; //presumably array of accounts
                     toastr.info('Acounts fetched', 'Account Read');
                }
            }
        },
        update: {
            url: '',
            type: 'POST',
            contentType: 'application/json',
            complete: function (response, errorThrown) {
                if (errorThrown === 'error') {
                    toastr.error(response.errorMessage, 'Account Update')
                } else {
                    toastr.info('Acount detail successfully updated', 'Account Update');
                }
            }
        }
    }
```